# Mac OS X video thumbnails

Tags: macos, mac, thumbnails

Mac OS X 10.6.2

When changing the default player for '.avi'- files (from Quicktime Player to VLC), I seem to lose the 'video thumbnails' in the 'icon view' in Finder.

Only a 'static vlc cone icon' remains (see picture)...

[image]

Any ideas ? This may seem like a trivial question but keep in mind that it's coming from a very new (2 day) Mac user (coming from Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLC doesn't have a QuickLook plugin, so the Finder can't use it to make the thumbnail.

A better solution to playing most AVI files is to install Perian, which adds a bunch of Microsoft codecs and containers to Quicktime, and therefore lets most apps play them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I will be looking into this tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

Since Perian's development was stopped, [QLVideo](https://github.com/Marginal/QLVideo) seems to be its rightful successor.